# Which javascript functions are in Google app script? Official list maintained by Google? reject supported or not?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I can find references to things like: 1.6, 1.7, ES5, ES6, ECMA-262 Edition 3, ECMAScript 2020, and many more but not a nice list. The links in old answers are to charts of standards not lists of functions.

I am watching and reading about javascript. Trying to reproduce training examples and I find array.reject(function... so I try it.

```
TypeError: zooPop.reject is not a function
```

I don't know if I am doing something wrong or this is not supported in App Scripts. Does Google maintain a list?  In stackoverflow I find statements that *soNso* is not supported but the date is a year or more ago. Now it is supported. Pulling out my hair.

Comment: The list is almost the same as found in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)  with the exception  of cutting edge  latest features

Comment: That function doesn't seem to be currently supported in the ECMAScript standard (on which Javascript is based). So GAS is not likely to support it either. Checked [can-i-use](https://caniuse.com/?search=Array.prototype.reject) and that function wasn't even listed. There are proposals floating around lobbying for support but they don't seem to be gaining any traction. I couldn't even find a polyfill for it.

Comment: @TheMaster  having a list that is almost the same / sort of correct is not very useful. I did a lot of searching for a definitive list. I would think Google would maintain one. Stackoverflow covers for Google's lack of documentation and I use it constantly.

Comment: @L.Klein Having a exact 100% definitive list is not worth the effort. I say "almost", but   you'll rarely run into any incompatibilities. Fix your IDE like Vscode/vim with Typescript and eslint/tslint set to ECMA2018 or 2019 and you should be good.

Comment: I am a retired mainframe programmer working in Google App Script to develope material for my parttime teaching ELL job. You are speaking Greek but thanks for replying